# How do I create a new variable with month and year instead of month, day and year

Tags: stata

I imported my Excel sheet into Stata. I want to create a new variable, with month and year from an Excel column field called month_year.

So how do I create a date variable ith only month and year?

I have unsuccessfully tried to use the `date()` function which uses two arguments, one the variable name and the other the MDY like `date(Date2,"MDY")` like `date(Date2,"MY")` but it's not working. I am using Stata 13.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you have and what you want? Hard to help without knowing what the data actually looks like. You can play around with dates with  `display %tm monthly("2018-11","YM",2000)` to get the right syntax for `monthly()`, and then use `generate` and `format` to actually create the variable.

Comment: It's documented that `date()` is for creating daily dates. `help date()` tells you that.

Comment: Hey, I'd faced the same issue and your solution worked! Thanks Farai.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found how this can be done. The code is as follows:

```
gen NEW_MONTH = monthly(MONTH, "M20Y")
format NEW_MONTH %tm
```

I then formatted into the required format from the new variable's properties to

```
Month Year
```

Comment: This is only a solution if data are in a certain form, and you never tell us exactly what yours look like.

Comment: I had a column in Excel called MONTH, with data in the form: Month, Year. for example January, 2010 February, 2010, March, 2010. I wanted to convert it to a date format for a time series data set

Comment: Exactly implies an example, not words. For example, Month could mean 12, Dec, December. Year could mean 18, 2018. Is the comma literal? It is good that you solved your problem, but the point of posting here is that solutions help others and how could anyone else  be certain that they have the same problem (or a different one)? Besides, it is what the data are like in Stata that a reader needs to know. To find out how to show example data from Stata in a forum like this, read `help dataex` (if necessary, install first with `ssc install dataex`).

Comment: The GUI way of doing it was giving me inacurate date, something like December 3084 for January, 2010

Comment: Sorry, but again, "the GUI way" means nothing to anyone else. You are saying "I used the menu and got the wrong answer". The only diagnosis likely is that you used the wrong functions.

Comment: `di %tm mdy(1, 1, 2010` may explain what you did.